# Configuring Amazon Name Servers for a transferred Domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I recently transferred some domains to amazons route53 from another provider. First I used the Name Server of another service. But now I want to change the Nameserver to Amazons own Name Severs.

How can I find out, what Name Server I should use?

Normally these are something like:

```
ns-480.awsdns-60.com
ns-1389.awsdns-45.org
ns-696.awsdns-23.net
ns-1639.awsdns-12.co.uk
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you log into your AWS account, go to the Route53 section, and click on the record set for your domain the very first record that it lists should be an NS record with the four DNS servers for your domain listed.